# Nginx Server Configuration - access folder

Tags: nginx

The domains on the server are accessible without an issue. I'd also like to access some folders independent from the domains.

file structure on the debain server:

```
+-- var
    +-- www
        +-- domains
            +-- domain.com
            +-- otherdomain.com
        +-- apps
            +-- folder1
                +-- index.php
```

for the domains I have a config file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`. The config from one domain looks like this: https://pastebin.com/S09DnEmv and is working.

Now I'd like to access `index.php` in `/var/www/apps/folder1/` which should be covered in the default config of nginx.

default config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
        }

        # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";

        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        # include the fastcgi_param setting
        include fastcgi_params;

    }

}
```

from my understanding using `root /var/www/;` I should be able to access the files in any folder. When I'm trying to access the files I land on the nginx default 404 page. This also happens when I try to access the server in the browser by only using the IP Address

Comment: well, all domain actually work the way they should. http and https with or without www are displaying the correct files in their own domain folder.

and I want to access some files only per ip address. and from my understanding, this can be made with the default.

Comment: What do you see in the access log and error log?

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a small issue I faced here.

In my default config I changed `server_name _;` to `server_name [IP ADDRESS GOES HERE];`